# How to add parameter to devextreme datasource LoadParams trough JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, devextreme

I'm trying to add a parameter to a DevExtreme SelectBox Datasource.
I'm trying to use the solution suggested by DevExtreme here [supportcenter.devexpress.com](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t421443/a-parameter-passed-to-the-loadparam-method-always-has-the-original-value/) like this:

```
<script>
function onGroupValueChanged(e) {
    let kpiSelectBox = $("#kpiSelectBox").dxSelectBox("instance");
    let dataSource = kpiSelectBox.getDataSource();
    dataSource.LoadParams(new { dataGroupId = new JS("function() { return e.value; }") })
    dataSource.load();
}
</script>
```

But I get an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

Anyone know how to do this?